# Elementor Pro Forms Validation

Tags: php, arrays, forms, elementor

I have a form with 3 simple fields: name, email and company. I am trying to get all the field values into vars but can't seem to understand how to iterate through them. I am getting my documentation from here: https://developers.elementor.com/forms-api

```
    add_action( 'elementor_pro/forms/validation', function ( $record, $ajax_handler ) {

      $raw_fields = $record->get( 'fields' );
      $fields = [];
      foreach ( $raw_fields as $field => $value) {
         $name = $value['name'];
         $email = $value['email'];
         $company = $value['company'];

//do something else with the vars

 }}, 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna do it like this:

```
$raw_fields = $record->get( 'fields' );
$fields = [];
foreach ( $raw_fields as $id => $field ) {
    $fields[ $id ] = $field['value']; //this is how you'd want to iterate all available fields
}
```

`$id` is the field's id you set on the form widget. Assuming you set the id of the *name* field as *name* then you can get the value like this `$fields['name']`.

Also, you might wanna check if you're on the right form before getting all the fields. You can try:

```
$form_id = $record->get_form_settings( 'form_id' );
if ( $form_id !== 'your_form_id' ) { //change this to your form id
    return;
}
```